# Can I use Sidekiq for continuous processes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background, sidekiq

I have several processes which currently run as rake tasks. Can I somehow use Sidekiq to execute a process in a continuous loop? Is that a best-practice with Sidekiq?

These processes, though they run in the background in a continuous loop in their respective rake tasks now, occasionally fail. Then I have to restart the rake task.

I am trying a couple of options, with help from the SO community. One is to figure out how to monitor the rake tasks with `monit`. But that means each process will have to have its own environment, adding to server load. Since I'm running in a virtualized environment, I want to eliminate that wherever possible.

The other option is just to leverage the Sidekiq option I already have. I use Sidekiq now for background processing, but it's always just one-offs. Is there some way I can have a continuous process in Sidekiq? And also be notified of failures and have the processes restart automatically?

Comment: Checking if questioner might have an answer for this since it has been a couple of months?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I amwanting a similar solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer per Mike Perham the Sidekiq author is to use a `cron` job for scheduled tasks like this. You can create a `rake` task which submits the job to `Sidekiq` to run in the background. Then create a `cron` job to schedule it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you go for sideki, is this project specific ? Previously I faced the same problem but I migrated to delayed_job and it satisfy my needs. If the active record objects are transactional use delayed_job otherwise go for resque it is also a nice one.

Comment: Most people have migrated to Sidekiq, because it doesn't have to spin up an entire Rails environment and you can run tons of jobs in parallel while incurring little system overhead.